# Advice on creating a "container" component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to create a "panel component" to hold x by y buttons (actually not exactly buttons, but you get the idea).

It should look like a minesweeper wherein you can click on any button and each has the same "global click" event. But with sender and button as parameters like: `Sender: TObject; Button: TButton`) wherin Sender being the panel component and Button the button inside the panel.

So far I put have two properties for the number of buttons in horizontal direction and the number of buttons in vertical direction.

```
  property ButtonsHeight: Integer read fButtonsHeight write SetButtonsHeight;
  property ButtonsWidth: Integer read fButtonsWidth  write SetButtonsWidth;

procedure TMultipleDrawPanel.SetButtonsHeight(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value < 1 then begin
    raise Exception.Create('Mumarul minim de butoane este 1!');
  end;
  InflateButtonsHeight(fButtonsHeight, Value);
  fButtonsHeight := Value;
end;
```

And this is the pseudo code for a change in the number of buttons in one direction:

```
procedure TMultipleDrawPanel.InflateButtonsHeight(oldValue, newValue: Integer);
begin
  if oldValue < newValue then begin
    // free extra buttons
  end else begin
    // create new buttons
  end;
end;
```

Can anyone point me to some advice?

1. How to store the list of buttons?
2. How to free the buttons when the number changes from a higher value to a lower value? (And how to create the new ones otherwise?)
3. I am sure I need to overide the resize method. I have some ideas but I did not get that far.

Comment: Usually this sort of thing works better as a single component rather than a compound component

Comment: Use a TGridPanel and place your buttons inside the cells.

Comment: tgridpanel is not what i need. what i expose here as the "panel component" is just the top of the iceberg.

Comment: Use a 2D array rather than trying to convert a 1D structure to a 2D one. You'll need to free then resize each column/row for shrinking or resize then add for expanding. I'd also use ButtonRows/ButtonCols rather than height/width as param names, as they have a different meaning.

Comment: You could implement you panel using TGridPanel.

Comment: _actually not exact button but you get the ideea_, no I don't get it: do you want buttons or not? All of the question is about buttons. If it doesn't have to be `TButton`, then which characteristics of a default button would you want to mimic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
unit ButtonPanel;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math;

type
  TCoord = record
    Col: Integer;
    Row: Integer;
  end;

  TCustomButtonPanel = class;

  TButtonClickEvent = procedure(Sender: TCustomButtonPanel;
    Coord: TCoord) of object;

  TCustomButtonPanel = class(Vcl.Controls.TWinControl)
  private
    FColCount: Integer;
    FOnClick: TButtonClickEvent;
    FRowCount: Integer;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    function CoordFromIndex(Index: Integer): TCoord;
    function CoordToIndex(Col, Row: Integer): Integer;
    function GetButton(Col, Row: Integer): TButton; overload;
    function GetButton(Index: Integer): TButton; overload;
    function GetButtonCount: Integer;
    procedure SetColCount(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetRowCount(Value: Integer);
    procedure SizeChanged;
  protected
    function CanResize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean; override;
    procedure DoClick(Index: Integer); virtual;
    procedure Resize; override;
    procedure ValidateInsert(AComponent: TComponent); override;
    property ButtonCount: Integer read GetButtonCount;
    property Buttons[Col, Row: Integer]: TButton read GetButton;
    property ColCount: Integer read FColCount write SetColCount default 5;
    property OnClick: TButtonClickEvent read FOnClick write FOnClick;
    property RowCount: Integer read FRowCount write SetRowCount default 5;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TButtonPanel = class(TCustomButtonPanel)
  public
    property ButtonCount;
    property Buttons;
  published
    property ColCount;
    property OnClick;
    property RowCount;
  end;

implementation

type
  TButtonPanelButton = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton);

resourcestring
  SInvalidControlType = 'Invalid control type for ButtonPanel child';

function Round(Value, Rounder: Integer): Integer; overload;
begin
  if Rounder = 0 then
    Result := Value
  else
    Result := (Value div Rounder) * Rounder;
end;

{ TCustomButtonPanel }

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoClick(TButton(Sender).Tag);
end;

function TCustomButtonPanel.CanResize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean;
var
  EdgeSize: Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited CanResize(NewWidth, NewHeight);
  EdgeSize := 2 * (BorderWidth + BevelWidth);
  NewWidth := Round(NewWidth - EdgeSize, FColCount) + EdgeSize;
  NewHeight := Round(NewHeight - EdgeSize, FRowCount) + EdgeSize;
end;

function TCustomButtonPanel.CoordFromIndex(Index: Integer): TCoord;
begin
  Result.Col := Index mod ColCount;
  Result.Row := Index div ColCount;
end;

function TCustomButtonPanel.CoordToIndex(Col, Row: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := FColCount * Row + Col;
end;

constructor TCustomButtonPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [];
  FColCount := 5;
  FRowCount := 5;
  SizeChanged;
end;

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.DoClick(Index: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnClick) then
    FOnClick(Self, CoordFromIndex(Index));
end;

function TCustomButtonPanel.GetButton(Col, Row: Integer): TButton;
begin
  Result := GetButton(CoordToIndex(Col, Row));
end;

function TCustomButtonPanel.GetButton(Index: Integer): TButton;
begin
  Result := TButton(Controls[Index]);
end;

function TCustomButtonPanel.GetButtonCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := ControlCount;
end;

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.Resize;
var
  ColWidth: Integer;
  RowHeight: Integer;
  Col: Integer;
  Row: Integer;
begin
  inherited Resize;
  ColWidth := ClientWidth div FColCount;
  RowHeight := ClientHeight div FRowCount;
  for Col := 0 to FColCount - 1 do
    for Row := 0 to FRowCount - 1 do
      Buttons[Col, Row].SetBounds(Col * ColWidth, Row * RowHeight, ColWidth,
        RowHeight);
end;

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.SetColCount(Value: Integer);
begin
  if FColCount <> Value then
  begin
    FColCount := Max(1, Value);
    SizeChanged;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.SetRowCount(Value: Integer);
begin
  if FRowCount <> Value then
  begin
    FRowCount := Max(1, Value);
    SizeChanged;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.SizeChanged;
var
  I: Integer;
  OldCount: Integer;
  NewCount: Integer;
  Button: TButton;
begin
  OldCount := ButtonCount;
  NewCount := FColCount * FRowCount;
  for I := OldCount - 1 downto NewCount do
    GetButton(I).Free;
  for I := OldCount to NewCount - 1 do
  begin
    Button := TButtonPanelButton.Create(Self);
    Button.Tag := I;
    Button.OnClick := ButtonClick;
    Button.Parent := Self;
  end;
  AdjustSize;
end;

procedure TCustomButtonPanel.ValidateInsert(AComponent: TComponent);
begin
  inherited ValidateInsert(AComponent);
  if not (AComponent is TButtonPanelButton) then
    raise EInvalidInsert.Create(SInvalidControlType);
end;

end.
```

I am sure the code above offers plenty of learning material, food for thought and room for customization. In short:

- I *misuse* the `Controls` property of the component to stretch its meaning to the buttons. Because of that, the control disallows insertion of other types of controls. See `GetButton`, `GetButtonCount`, `ValidateInsert`.
- Because each button has the same size, and the component is completely filled with buttons, the size of the component is limited to a multiple of a button's size. See `CanResize`.
- It has an reintroduced `OnClick` event, because the panel self won't be clicked (it is full with buttons). The event has an extra parameter, see `ButtonClick`, `DoClick`.
- The 2D column-row coordinates are mapped to a linear array of indices, see `CoordFromIndex`, `CoordToIndex`.
- The buttons are identified by the `Tag` property, see `SizeChanged` wherein the buttons are created.

The next step for you is to redesign this with a virtual approach whereby no actual `TButton` controls are used but where buttons are just drawn mimicry.

Have fun.

Comment: tks alot.i get the ideea and i will develop further.